# iOS compress jpg not in a right size

Tags: ios, image-processing, compression

I try to compress a jpg with 0.4 quality. I printed the data size using NSlog, it shows the NSData size is 337613, but after save to album, the file was increased to 677947.

What can I do with this? 
PS: image object is from Camera.

```
NSData *newData =UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.3f);
UIImage *compressdImg30 = [UIImage imageWithData:newData];
NSLog(@"[after 0]newData.length=%u",[newData length]); // print 337613 in debug
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressdImg30,nil,nil,nil);
```

then I plug iPhone and copy the file to my Mac Mini, and type "ls -ltr" to see the file size, then showing 677947.

Comment: Show the relevant code by updating your question.

Comment: code added now :) thanks!

Comment: And where's the code to add the image to the photo album?

Comment: I'm not seeing what data are you writing to file

Comment: You are writing compressdImg30 to the file but printing the size of newData, these are two separate things so the sized of the file will not match the size of newData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ALAssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:)'s
 
`-writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:`

 method to save image data to library.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *al = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[al writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:data metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Completion block/Do check the error if any");
}];
```

Try it and see

Comment: Thanks!  But could I control the jpg quality rate in a spec value. I found the after compressed, the actual quality rate is not the value I spec in the function.